# C# Copy User Defined Number of Files

Tags: c#, file, copy

I am attempting to copy a set number of files from one directory to another. My code in its current state copies all files within a directory. I believe I would need a list, or an array, but am somewhat new to C#, so wanted to bring my question here. An example would be to copy 20 files from the directory specified in the code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
}
private void CopyFiles(int numberOfFiles)
    {
        List<string> files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\acars\Desktop\A", "*").ToList();
        IEnumerable<string> filesToCopy = files.Where(file => file.Contains("Test_Test")).Take(20);

        foreach (string file in filesToCopy)
        {
            // here we set the destination string with the file name
            string destfile = @"C:\Users\acars\Desktop\B\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
            // now we copy the file to that destination
            System.IO.File.Copy(file, destfile, true);
        };
```

Comment: You say in your text that you want to copy a set number of files, but in your code you filter them and copy all that pass. Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Of the files in the directory, how do you want to select which 20 files you copy?

Comment: Thank you for the responses. There are two types of naming conventions in the folder: Test_Test and NonTest_NonTest. There are about 500 of each. I would like to copy the top 20 files with the naming convention Test_Test. They can be any of the Test_Test files, as long as there are only 20.

Comment: How do you define top 20? Name? Modified date?

Comment: Modified date would define the top 20

Answer (score 0):

With a few modifications your code is able to copy a given number of files. The following example takes the first x files from your directory:

```
    private void CopyFiles(int numberOfFiles)
        {
            List<string> files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\rando\Desktop\A", "*").ToList();
            IEnumerable<string> filesToCopy = files.Where(file => file.Contains("Test_Test")).Take(numberOfFiles);

            foreach (string file in filesToCopy)
            {
                // here we set the destination string with the file name
                string destfile = @"C:\Users\rando\Desktop\B\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
                // now we copy the file to that destination
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, destfile, true);
            }
        }
```

If you want the first x files according to a special order, you have to order the "files" list first.

Comment: I get an error that looks like it is missing a Cast function somewhere. I also don't see where I would be able to define the number of files, but I may be missing it since I'm new to this. I tried declaring the numberOfFiles variable and setting to 20, but it said the value was never used. I may be doing it in the wrong place. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer so that it uses IEnumerable for the second list.You can pass any number to this function, and the .Take() will process you as many files as you specified.

Comment: So in the filesToCopy variable I just replaced .Take(numberOfFiles) with .Take(20). The program runs without error, but does not copy any files over now. Should I be defining 20 somewhere else?

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues here, the 20 can be used as a constant as well. What can occur is that you don't have any files matching the given criteria. Apart from this, since you want to order by the date of modification, you should consider the answer from @jdphenix , because as he said you will have to use the FileInfo class.

Comment: Maybe something with =>? The Files start with integers such as        12345-Test_Test. However, I would think file.contains searches the entire file name.

Comment: I can't figure this out. Above is my edited code set. Maybe it's how              something is placed.

Comment: In your Main() you have to call the new function to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to order by information about the file beyond the name, you'll need to use `FileInfo`. Here's what I believe to be a straightforward implementation that should get you started.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    var path = Path.Combine(desktop, "A");
    var outPath = Path.Combine(desktop, "B");

    Copy(20, "file", path, outPath, x => x.LastWriteTimeUtc);
}

static void Copy<T>(int count, string filter, string inputPath, string outputPath, Func<FileInfo, T> order)
{
    new DirectoryInfo(inputPath).GetFiles()
        .OrderBy(order)
        .Where(file => file.Name.Contains(filter))
        .Take(count)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(file => File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(outputPath, file.Name), true));
}
```

To use this, you would pass in the number to copy, the paths, a filter, and an ordering action.

- `new DirectoryInfo(inputPath).GetFiles()` - Get a `FileInfo[]` of every file in the specified path
- `.OrderBy(order)` - order them
- `.Where(file => file.Name.Contains(filter))` - filter by the passed in filter
- `.Take(count)` - take the count
- `.ToList()` - convert to List to use ForEach
- `.ForEach(file => File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(outputPath, file.Name), true))` - Make the File.Copy() call for each